# How to Append Prefix Value in AngularJs model text box dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have over 50 text box elements in page. I am trying to append minus symbol in every text box after enter value (ng-blur) by using one common javascript function. but i am unable to pass ng-model name to javascript function from jsp element ng-blur call to append minus symbol after enter  value. any solution.

JSP element:

```
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" 
ng-blur="appendMinusSymbol('buzz.model1.rate')" ng-model="buzz.model1.rate"/>

    <input type="text" maxlength="10" 
ng-blur="appendMinusSymbol('buzz.model2.rate')" ng-model="buzz.model2.rate"/>
```

JS Function:

```
$scope.appendMinusSymbol = function(model){
// append minus symbol as prefix to ng model value
};
```

Note : Edited my question (model1, model2, model3 like having 50 fields)

Comment: Can't you use a directive for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my solution on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avgustin/f2bspc0h/1/). If you can, then pass only model name like in the fiddle, otherwise you will need additional parsing.  Of course you need here additional check when to append minus sign if already exists.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" ng-blur="appendMinusSymbol('model1')" ng-model="buzz.model1.rate"/>

$scope.appendMinusSymbol = function(modelName){      
    $scope.buzz[modelName]['rate'] = '-'+$scope.buzz[modelName]['rate'];
};
```

Comment: how to call if modelName is buzz.model1.rate, buzz.model2.rate and so on.. i need to pass model1.rate as paramter. please look my edited question

Comment: @deadend I have upadated my answer.

Comment: @deadend Or check updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avgustin/v3bmtk1h/1/